# AFNetworking 2.0 : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager asynchronous methode invoke

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 for networking of my application, I have implemented a method to check the login of a user

```
-(NSString *) loginWith : (NSString *) email andPassword :(NSString *) password
{
    __block NSString * result ;

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"email": email, @"password": password};

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:[kROOT_URL stringByAppendingString:@"auth/"] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", (NSDictionary*)responseObject);

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:responseObject forKey:USER_KEY];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        result = [responseObject objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"result :: %@",result);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

        result = nil;

    }];

    return result;
}
```

and from other view controller I am invoking this method :

```
NSString * result = [self.user loginWith:emailCell.textField.text andPassword:passCell.textField.text];

NSLog(@"Result: %@",result);
```

the problem is that I get "null" as the object of result, This is because that when the NSlog is executed the network process was doing in background thread, so how I correct the implementation, so then I can get the result in the right moment, after fetching

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a “callback“ block parameter to your method signature, and call that block when the request is done.

```
- (void)loginWith:(NSString *)email andPassword:(NSString *)password complete:(void(^)(id result, NSError *error))block {

    // ...

    [manager POST:[kROOT_URL stringByAppendingString:@"auth/"] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {

        // ...

        result = [responseObject objectForKey:@"id"];

        if (block) block(result, nil)

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {

        if (block) block(nil, error)

    }];

}
```

When calling the method, pass the callback block where you can read the result value:

```
[self.user loginWith:emailCell.textField.text andPassword:passCell.textField.text complete:^(id result, NSError *error) {
     if (error)
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     else
         NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help; it really works, but I just wanna know it it's a good practice, since I really care about that.